# Media Queries only work with !important even after putting it in the end of the stylesheet

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries, css-grid

I making a glassmorphism mac app store UI in HTML AND SCSS.
But when I use media queries to change a property that was already defined, I cannot do it without the `!important` keyword..

In the grid div (which is inside trending section) I have used `display: grid;` and when I try to change the number of rows and columns in the `@media (max-width: 768px)`, I have to use the `!important` keyword. I visited other similar questions and they said to put the
`@media(max-width: 768px){...}` in the end to prevent using `!important` which is what I did. The only difference is that I am using **sass/scss** which you can see in this codepen - [SCSS Code](https://codepen.io/Aviral_Coder/pen/rNyZBwX).

I don't want to use the `!important keyword` because it is a bad practise and I have to show this project to my teacher.

How to prevent from using `!important`??

HTML AND CSS (css made by the live sass compiler vscode extension)

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap");
* {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

:root {
    --container-height: 90%;
    --container-width: 90%;
    --component-background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}

body {
    background: url("https://4kwallpapers.com/images/wallpapers/macos-big-sur-apple-layers-fluidic-colorful-dark-wwdc-2020-5120x2880-1432.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.container {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: var(--container-width);
    height: var(--container-height);
    position: relative;
}

header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

section.window--buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
}

section.window--buttons .window__close {
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    background: #f00;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

section.window--buttons .window__close:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

section.window--buttons .window__minimize {
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    background: #f57c00;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

section.window--buttons .window__minimize:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

section.window--buttons .window__maximize {
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    background: #4caf50;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

section.window--buttons .window__maximize:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

aside {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 90%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

aside button {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0.7rem 4rem;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    background: none;
    width: 170px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

aside button:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}

aside button.active {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}

aside input[type="text"] {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    width: 170px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0.9rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
    color: white;
}

aside input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
}

aside input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    text-align: center;
}

aside input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    text-align: center;
}

aside input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
}

aside .profile {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    bottom: 15px;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

aside .profile .profile--pic {
    width: 4rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

aside .profile h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.content {
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 90%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.content .ideas {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.content .ideas .idea {
    background: var(--component-background);
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.content .ideas .idea:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.content .ideas .idea p {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.content .ideas .idea:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.06);
    transform: scale(1.06);
}

.content .updates {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.content .updates h1:nth-of-type(1) {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
}

.content .updates .update {
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--component-background);
    padding: 1.3rem 0.7rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.content .updates .update:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
    transform: scale(1.03);
}

.content .updates .update .updt-left {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.content .updates .update .updt-left h1 {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.content .updates .update .updt-left img {
    width: 35px;
}

.content .updates .update .buttons button {
    background: none;
    color: dodgerblue;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.content .updates .update .buttons button:hover {
    color: blue;
}

.content .trending {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.content .trending h1:nth-last-of-type(1) {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
}

.content .trending .grid {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-rows: (25%) [4];
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 25%);
    -ms-grid-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    gap: 5px;
}

.content .trending .grid .grid__app {
    background: var(--component-background);
    padding: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: -webkit-fit-content;
    height: -moz-fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.content .trending .grid .grid__app.margin {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.content .trending .grid .grid__app h1 {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}

.content .trending .grid .grid__app button {
    background: dodgerblue;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 30%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content .links {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: (50%) [2];
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
    -ms-grid-rows: (50%) [2];
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50%);
}

.content .links a {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.content .links a:nth-of-type(3),
.content .links a:nth-of-type(4) {
    margin-top: 7px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%) !important;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 25%) !important;
    }
    aside {
        display: none;
    }
    .links {
        margin-top: 50px;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MacOS App Store</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <header>
            <section class="window--buttons">
                <div class="window__close"></div>

                <div class="window__minimize"></div>

                <div class="window__maximize"></div>
            </section>
        </header>

        <aside>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" /><br />

                <button class="active" id="sidebar-btn">Discover</button>
                <button id="sidebar-btn">Arcade</button>
                <button id="sidebar-btn">Create</button>
                <button id="sidebar-btn">Work</button>
                <button id="sidebar-btn">Play</button>
                <button id="sidebar-btn">Develop</button>
                <button id="sidebar-btn">Categories</button>
                <button id="sidebar-btn">Updates</button>
            </div>

            <div class="profile">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/994592419705274369/RLplF55e.jpg" alt="Profile Pic"
                    class="profile--pic" />

                <h1>Jimmy Donaldson</h1>
            </div>
        </aside>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="ideas">
                <div class="idea">
                    <p>MASTER YOUR MAC</p>
                    <h1>Make a great<br> handoff</h1>
                    <p>Work seamlessly across devices</p>
                </div>

                <div class="idea">
                    <p>GET STARTED</p>
                    <h1>Apps optimised for mac with M1</h1>
                    <p>Work seamlessly across devices</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <section class="updates">
                <h1>Updates</h1>

                <div class="update update-1">

                    <div class="updt-left">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/452/microsoft-powerpoint-2019.png"
                            alt="powerpoint icon" />
                        <h1>Microsoft Powerpoint</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="buttons">
                         <button>Update</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="update">

                    <div class="updt-left">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/452/microsoft-word-2019--v2.png" alt="word icon" />
                        <h1>Microsoft Word</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="buttons">
                        <button style="color: lime;cursor: default">Updated</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="update">

                    <div class="updt-left">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Adobe_Photoshop_Lightroom_CC_logo.svg/788px-Adobe_Photoshop_Lightroom_CC_logo.svg.png"
                            alt="lightroom icon" />
                        <h1>Adobe Lightroom</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="buttons">
                            <button>Update</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="update">

                    <div class="updt-left">
                        <img src="https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/images/app-icon-realistic-materials_2x.png"
                            alt="xcode icon" />
                        <h1>Xcode</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="buttons">
                         <button>Update</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="trending">
                <h1>Trending</h1>

                <div class="grid">
                    <span class="grid__app">
                        <h1>Kindle</h1>

                        <button>GET</button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="grid__app">
                        <h1>Slac</h1>

                        <button>GET</button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="grid__app">
                        <h1>Magnet</h1>

                        <button>₹699</button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="grid__app">
                        <h1>CotEditor</h1>

                        <button>GET</button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="grid__app margin">
                        <h1>Twitter</h1>

                        <button>GET</button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="grid__app margin">
                        <h1>Notability</h1>

                        <button>₹799</button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="grid__app margin">
                        <h1>NDTV</h1>

                        <button>GET</button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="grid__app margin">
                        <h1>Rummy</h1>

                        <button>₹179</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="links">
                <a href="#">Privacy Policy -></a>

                <a href="#">Terms and Conditions -></a>

                <a href="#">Report Error -></a>

                <a href="#">
                    Parent's guide to Mac app store
                </a>
            </section>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: instead of .grid {} in the media queries use .content .trending .grid {} since this will get precedence above .grid as it is nested... hope that makes sense

Comment: you must always keep in mind how the [specificity](https://specifishity.com/) works for css

Comment: @Navnit you should write this up as an answer so Aviral can mark it as solved